# Careers' Profile - Print

Tags: bug, status-completed, jobs, feedback

I found a bug in careers' profile. When I click print in the sidebar, it opens the printable version in a new tab, but destroys the current page. It just displays: `[object Window]`.

I used firefox on linux - not sure about the other browsers.

Comment: Repro with Firefox 28 and IE 11, no repro with Chrome 34.

Comment: Thanks @Stijn for the repro information, very useful!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This bug has been fixed, thank you for the report!